# Auto space after symbol when user typing into input

Tags: javascript, html

I have input[type=text] where user can type only alpha, space and comma. 
I need that after each comma in "input" js put a space.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example with JQuery:

```
$("#landing-search-input").keyup(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 188) {
        $(this).val($(this).val() + " ");
    }
});
```

or

```
$("#landing-search-input").keyup(function(event) {
    var inputValue = $(this).val();
    if (inputValue.substr(-1) == ",") {
        $(this).val(inputValue + " ");
    }
});
```

Comment: This won't work when the caret is not at the end of the input text.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this properly so that

1. a space is added in the correct place when the caret is not at the end of the input text
2. the caret is placed correctly immediately after the space after insertion

... you'll need something like the following, which will work in all major browsers, including IE 6.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Y9c6G/

Code:

```
function insertTextAtCursor(el, text) {
    var val = el.value, endIndex, range;
    if (typeof el.selectionStart != "undefined" 
            && typeof el.selectionEnd != "undefined") {
        endIndex = el.selectionEnd;
        el.value = val.slice(0, endIndex) + text + val.slice(endIndex);
        el.selectionStart = el.selectionEnd = endIndex + text.length;
    } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined"
             && typeof document.selection.createRange != "undefined") {
        el.focus();
        range = document.selection.createRange();
        range.collapse(false);
        range.text = text;
        range.select();
    }
}

document.getElementById("some_input").onkeypress = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var charCode = typeof evt.which == "number" ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (String.fromCharCode(charCode) == ",") {
        insertTextAtCursor(this, ", ");
        return false;
    }
};
```